What is the specific meaning of the word "let" according to King James translators in the 1611 time frame?
Isaiah 43:13

Yea, before the day was I am he; and there is none that can deliver
out of my hand: I will work, and who shall 'let' it?

Did the word 'let' mean oppose and NOT allow as we think of today?

@ Dottard, @ Perry Webb, @ Brian Gridley, @ David. - Thank you all for your participation. It has been a learning experience. The use of the little 3 letter word " let " is enigmatic. It would seem that in certain context the meaning can be almost opposite to others. I went to the use in Gen. 1 where let there be is used about 12 times and found the Strong's had no number for the Hebrew word used for " let ". The answer if I interpreted correctly was that it was added so English readers would better understand. If that is the case , God actually just said " be light"

@ Dottard feel free to enlighten us on this.

The KJV phrase "who shall 'let' it" translates וּמִ֥י יְשִׁיבֶֽנָּה.  This may be a shift in the meaning of let since the KJV was translated.
"Did the word 'let' mean oppose and NOT allow as we think of today?"
That's very close.
See https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED25277/track?counter=1&search_id=76765464
וּ means and.
מִ֥י means who.
יְשִׁיבֶֽנָּה is hiphil, imperfect, 3rd person masculine singular of שׁוב with the (direct object) suffix 3rd person feminine singular
שׁוב - This root means return.
Hiphil tends to mean to cause what the root means.  Thus, the hiphil of שׁוב means to undo or referse.
  Ever since day was, I am He; 
  None can deliver from My hand. 
  When I act, who can reverse it?
                (Isa. 43:13, JPS1985)

“Even from eternity I am He;
  And there is none who can deliver out of My hand;
  I act and who can reverse it?”
                (Isa. 43:13, NASB1986)

 Also henceforth I am he; 
  there is none who can deliver from my hand; 
  I work, and who can turn it back?”
                 (Isa. 43:13, ESV2016)


In this context, "let it" seems to mean "take it from me".  The etymology(see https://www.etymonline.com/word/let) suggests "let it go" hence the idea "who can make God let go of it", essentially reiterating the "none can deliver out of my hand" fact.
A New Testament example of a similar reiteration [Jhn 10:28-29 NIV] 28 I give them eternal life, and they shall never perish; no one will snatch them out of my hand. 29 My Father, who has given them to me, is greater than all; no one can snatch them out of my Father's hand.

The following give a good rendering of the literal Hebrew meaning of Isa 43:13:

NASB: “Even from eternity I am He, And there is no one who can rescue from My hand; I act, and who can reverse it?”
NKJV: Indeed before the day was, I am He; And there is no one who can deliver out of My hand; I work, and who will reverse it?”

The KJV 1611 version has a marginal note against the phrase "let it", viz:

Heb: turne it backe, Iob 9,12, chap 14, 17

The phrase in the KJV of "let it" appears to be a hang-over from the Bishops' Bible of 1568 and the Geneva Bible of 1587.

There are two different words: letten, "make late" and letan "leave, leave undone".
Both "words" were in use in the 1600's, but I'm not sure if the other word (leave, leave undone) is used at all in the KJV?
The "make late, hinder, obstruct", word is retained in the legal phrase from approximately the same date: "without let or hinderance" and in the rules of tennis: a "let", when the ball touches the net (hindered, obstructed) causes the point to be replayed.
The two words came into English by different paths, from different sources.
